# Print unmatched patterns not the unmatched content of file, using grep

Tags: bash, macos, unix, grep

I'm using grep command in bash to find multiple keywords/patterns which did not find a match

For example below command returns the keywords/patterns that matched

> grep -oehE '(cat|dog|apple|mango|bat)' temp.txt | sort | uniq

But I'm looking for a command which can do following:

```
temp.txt contains
This is a dog the best
Dog are the best
doG
dog
My best buddy is dog
Love mango and candy
```

The output of search I'm looking for is

```
cat 
apple
bat
```

The output is the patterns that did not match the data in the file.

I searched for a similar problem and the closest I could find was below post but it deals with the files rather than all on the command line

[Similar problem using file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194700/print-unmatched-patterns-using-grep-with-patterns-from-file)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is actually "how to get unmatched alternatives listed in the regex", right?

Comment: What is your input ?  file or a string?  What is the input from which you need to filter out non matching records

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you elaborate. I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: I think I am right after seeing the edit. But you can't do this, it is just not how regexps work with grep or any other tool/method. You need to test the alternatives separately with `grep`, and only keep/use those that do not match. You can't use an alternation based pattern to get the alternatives that did not match. At least like this and in `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you could:

```
$ awk -v p="cat|dog|apple|mango|bat" '  # search words
BEGIN {                                 # first make hash of the search words
    split(p,t,/\|/)
    for(i in t)
        a[t[i]]
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                   # for each record and word in the record
        delete a[$i]                     # remove them from the hash
}
END {                                    # in the end
    for(i in a)                          # in order that appears random
        print i                          # output the leftovers
}' temp.txt
```

and have the output of:

```
bat
apple
cat
```

<s>With `grep`:</s>

```
$ echo "cat|dog|apple|mango|bat" | tr \| \\n > pats
$ grep -vf temp.txt pats
cat
apple
bat
```

<s>With `grep` without involvment of files:</s>

```
$ echo -e cat\\ndog\\napple\\nmango\\nbat | grep -vf temp
cat
apple
bat
```

Comment: With grep you are sill storing it in the file. Thanks for suggesting Awk. Let me know if this can be achieved using grep but without the involvement of files.

Comment: Updated with another `grep`.

Comment: This is very limited to sample in the question. I guess I would have phrased it better. It fails on input file containing "this is a dog the best
Love mango and candy". I have edited the problem description.

Comment: It was a precise answer to your original question where each record had just one word. This edited (awk) version loops all words in the record so it works with your new sample. The `grep` version is now obsolete.

Comment: Yes you are correct and that's why I changed the description when I saw the gap in understanding. Thanks alot for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun, if you have only words (so no deal with spaces ard special characters) and few of them (in the limit of the command line) you may use as many call to grep as terms to check so

```bash
for p in cat dog apple mango bat; do grep -qsw "$p" temp.txt || echo "$p"; done
```

Here, each word is echoed back if not found in the file.

Anyway the `awk` alternative is better because you don't spaw the process many times.

Answer (score 0):

this doens't guarantee collation order, so you'll have to `sort` it manually if necessary

> ```
>  mawk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '
>        {  __[$_]
>  } END {     FS = "|"
>              $_ = ___
>          for (_ = +_; _++ < NF; _++) { 
>             if ( ! ( $_ in __ ) ) { 
>                print $_           } } }' ___='cat|dog|apple|mango|bat'
> ```

```
cat
apple
bat
```